# Robot.txt how to allow a page that ends with /, but disallow all pages after /

Tags: seo

Im trying to figure out how to only allow the bot to crawl my homepage which is like this: `blabla.no/homepage/` (it must be like this)

I want to

```
allow: /homepage/
```

But at the same time 
`disallow /homepage/*`   (everything that comes after) Only the homepage shall be crawlable.

I know that if you end the instruction with `/`, you don't need to add `*` or `$`, so how do I this? Was this understandable?

Comment: Perfect, thanx! Hope this rule still works today.

Comment: If you would accept the duplicate it will help others looking for this problem

Comment: By accept the duplicate, you mean delete this post?